# Using node-schedule to run at *specific* times

Tags: javascript, node-schedule

Using node-scheduler to set up recurring job.  I need 7 days a week at several *specific* times - e.g. 5:45am, 06:30am, 11:15am, etc.

I set up rule:

```
let rule = new schedule.RecurrenceRule();
rule.dayOfWeek = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

Now if I add hours and minutes as arrays it looks like they run through all hours for all minutes - e.g.

```
rule.hour = [5,6,11];
rule.minute = [45,30,15];
```

So, *this* will run at 5:45am, 6:45am, 11:45am, 5:30am, 6:30am, 11:30am, ....

How can I use rules to set up for exact times?  Again, in my example 5:45am, 06:30am, 11:15am

Answer (score 4):

Another approach is to use [Object Literal Syntax](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule#object-literal-syntax). If the weekday is not specified as shown below the times apply for being scheduled each day.

```
let times = [
  {hour: 5, minute: 45}, 
  {hour: 6, minute: 30}, 
  {hour: 11, minute: 15}
];
times.forEach(function(time) {
  var j = schedule.scheduleJob(time, function() {
    // your job
    console.log('Time for tea!');
  });
})
```

Answer (score 2):

The `node-schedule` module seems to support cron syntax. But as the schedule you want, cannot be expressed in a single rule with cron, you also can't define that in a single rule in node-schedule. Using the `dayOfWeek`, `hour` and `minute` definitions for the rule schedules the job on every combination of `day`, `hour` and `minute`, like a cron rule does.

Have a look at the [recurrence rule scheduling](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule#recurrence-rule-scheduling) section in the docs, how to define a rule for a specific time every day, and create and schedule a separate rule for each time you need

```
let hour = [5, 6, 11];
let minute = [45, 30, 15];

for (let i = 0; i < hour.length; i++) {
  let rule = new schedule.RecurrenceRule();
  rule.dayOfWeek = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
  rule.hour = hour[i];
  rule.minute = minute[i];

  let j = schedule.scheduleJob(rule, function(){
    //your job
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I originally set it up similar to the the code you both offered above but was trying to get it all into a single rule.  I visually display the jobs with their next invocation in a table and preferred a single job (name) to list in the table.  I'm going to research a bit more and post back here if I come up w/anything else.  Thanks again for the prompt feedback!